# Why does a syntax error happen in my code?

Tags: python-3.x, string, count, syntax-error

The string method I want to use:

s.count(sub[, start[, end]])

A syntax error occurs at the first comma.

An error occurs at the first comma, so I checked several times if all the '[' signs or the ')' signs are used as a set(as in 'closed').

```
s = input("Enter a sentence that contains at least 4 words: ")

print("c) ", ljust(s, 50, fillchar='/'))
print("d)", s.count('oh'[, 1[, 5]]))
print("e)", s.index('oh'[, 1[, 5]]))
```

The first comma inside the count method shows an invalid syntax error.
Just for your reference, I attached the line before and after the erroneous code, as well.
Is there a parentheses that is not closed, or are there any errors besides the one I have thought about?

Comment: The square brackets in the documentation means they are optional. You don't literally add them.

Answer (score 1):

You're misreading the syntax of `s.count`.

```
s.count(sub[, start[, end]])
```

What that means is that you call `count` with the substring, optionally followed by a starting position (the `[, start` portion), and if that optional start position is provided it can be followed by an optional `end` (the `[, end` portion). The two `]]` at the end before the closing parenthesis are the closures for the two optional portions.

What all that means is that you can call `count` in any of these three ways:

- By passing a substring only

  ```
  s.count(sub)
  ```
- By passing a substring and the place to start

  ```
  s.count(sub, 5)
  ```
- By passing a substring, the place to start, and the place to stop

  ```
  s.count(sub, 5, 15)
  ```

(BTW, you're going to have the same issue for the same reason with `s.index` on the next line once you correct this one.)